# Emptying IIS website before automatic web deployment from TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, web-deployment

I'm automatically publishing a web project after build from TFS 2012 by using a publishing profile (I have a build definition on TFS that has /p:DeployOnBuild,PublishProfile... etc. as additional MSBuild arguments). Everything works fine. However, since my web site creates some temporary local folders I'd like to clean up before the next automatic deployment. Is there a way to easily clean up? Maybe some additional MSBuild argument?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to using Release Management for Visual Studio 2013. I have had it Woking fore more than one customer with 2012. You can then create orchestration that is specifically designed for deployment rather than compilation.

- [Release Management with Visual Studio 2013](http://nakedalm.com/installing-release-management-server-tfs-2013/)